# Python Index out of range?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, arabic, wordnet

I am using arabic wordnet to find synonyms; it works fine using the code below and it outputs the correct synonym:

```
import unicodedata
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
yxz='work'
jan = wn.synsets(yxz)[0]
abc=jan.lemma_names(lang='arb')
for bca in abc: #Converting from unicode to arabic done
    nfkd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', bca)
    encoded=nfkd_form.encode('utf-8')#this works fine
    encoded= u"".join([c for c in nfkd_form if not unicodedata.combining(c)])
    print encoded
```

However I want to iterate over the above part and I change the word(yxz) every time but it doesn't work because index is out of range: (I have an XML document I want to get the synonyms for the verbs only in certain sentence, verbs are present between the tag `<v>` in the XML document)

```
Synonyms=[]

for phrase in root.findall('./PHRASE'):
  ens = {en.get('x'): en.text for en in phrase.findall('en')}
  if 'ORG' in ens and 'PERS' in ens:
    if (((ens["ORG"] ==u"جامعة بيت لحم" )and (ens["PERS"]==u" ه أحمد")) or ((ens["ORG"] ==u"جامعة كولومبيا." )and (ens["PERS"]==u"رئيس الجمهورية السيد محمد المنصف المرزوقي")) or ((ens["ORG"] ==u"معمل باريكادي " )and (ens["PERS"]==u"رئيس فنزويلا")) or ((ens["ORG"] ==u"شركة جوجل" )and (ens["PERS"]==u"لاري بيدج وسيرغي برين")) or((ens["ORG"] ==u"محترفه الباريسي" )and (ens["PERS"]==u"بول"))):
     for v in phrase.findall('V'):
                    #----------------------------------------ENGLISH SYNONYM TRIAL---------------------------

          print("------ English Synonym Trial----------")
          #-------Step 8.3] Google Translate API working fine ) now want it to translate from ar to en from Diacritics----------
          #-----8.3.1] Translate Diactrics Array words to english-----------------------
          gs = goslate.Goslate()
          engVerb=gs.translate(unicode(v.text), 'en') #english word is the output
          print("---EngVerb---")
          print(engVerb)
          #-----8.3.2] use Arabic Wordnet to get the synonyms[English->output unicode] Working -----------------------
          #yxz='work'
          jan = wn.synsets(engVerb)[0]
          abc=jan.lemma_names(lang='arb')
          for bca in abc: #Converting from unicode to arabic done
             nfkd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', bca)
             encoded=nfkd_form.encode('utf-8')#this works fine
             encoded= u"".join([c for c in nfkd_form if not unicodedata.combining(c)])
             #print encoded
             Synonyms.append(encoded)
print("----------------------------PRINTING SYNONYMS---------------------------")
print Synonyms
```

However I always get the error

```
 jan = wn2.synsets(engVerb)[0]
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

That error means that `wn2.synsets(engVerb)` is an empty list (use `print` to debug, it helps a lot), and you are trying to access its first element which does not exist.

Try this instead:

```
x = wn2.synsets(engVerb)
if len(x) == 0:
    continue
else:
    jan = x[0]
```